# spring auto-wire failed when inject a dependent bean into a @component java class

Tags: spring, components

I have a Service class with @Component annotation, and this bean dependent a DAO like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomerService
{

    @Setter
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

}
```

and XML file goes like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.customer" />
<bean id="customerDAO" class="com.mkyong.customer.dao.CustomerDAO" autowire="byName"></bean>
```

But, after the app is running, the field customerDAO can't been injected. If I replace `@Setter` with `@Resource`, that's will be fine. I deeply wonders, why the `@Componet` bean can't be injected with setter methods.

I'm using Spring 2.5.6;

Comment: XML file: <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.customer" />

 <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.mkyong.customer.dao.CustomerDAO" autowire="byName"></bean>

Comment: There is no `@Setter` annotation in Spring. `@Component` and `@Resource` are synonyms. `@Resource` is annotation from JSR-250, and Spring just supports it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to inject on setter, you will have to create a setter and annotate it with `@Autowired`.

```
@Component
public class CustomerService {

    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }
}
```